# Scroll doesn't work with iOS simulator using appium

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, appium, appium-ios

I am automating an app on iPhone (simulator) where I need to swipe through the pages (splash pages in the very beginning) after the app launch
Making use of swipe function doesn't work :

```
driver.swipe(337, 420, 70, 420, 2000); (driver - IOSDriver)
```

Tried other options such as executing a `.js` for implementing the same which didn't work either. And tried many more solutions found online. None worked in my case. Somewhere I read that swipe is not supported in versions 7 and above. Is that true? Or is there any workaround?

> I have latest versions of Xcode, Appium Xcode : 7.3 Appium : 1.4.13
>   (Draco) Running on iPhone 6 simulator (8.4)

Is there a way by any chance I could perform this??

Answer (score 0):

For Scroll View :-

```
[MyScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];    
[MyScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,620)];    
[self.view addSubview:MyScroller];
```

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate little more? Are these the flags I need to set? if so, where?

Comment: If Your Scroll View Not Working Okay So You Have To Put That Code On  And Add in To Subview Try it